# pgbouncer can't connect to local postgresql database (timeout)

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

Im trying to get pgbouncer to work on my standalone postgresql server, but when I try to connect to the database using the pgbouncer port, I get an timeout error.

Postgresql: 9.1.8

pgBouncer: 1.4.2

OS: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.4-x86_64-linode31 x86_64)

Here is my conf file:

```
[databases]
postgres = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=postgres
mydb = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=mydb

[pgbouncer]
logfile = /home/username/pg_log/pgbouncer.log
pidfile = /tmp/pgbouncer.pid
listen_addr = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
listen_port = 6432
unix_socket_dir = /var/run/postgresql
auth_type = md5
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
admin_users = postgres
stats_users = stats, root
user = postgres
pool_mode = session
server_reset_query = DISCARD ALL
max_client_conn = 1000
default_pool_size = 20
log_connections = 1
log_disconnections = 1
log_pooler_errors = 1
```

Im trying to test the connection like this:

```
psql -p 6432 -U postgres mydb
```

Here is my log file:

```
28396 LOG listening on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6432
28396 LOG listening on unix:/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.6432
28396 LOG process up: pgbouncer 1.4.2, libevent 2.0.16-stable (epoll), adns: evdns2
28864 LOG C-0x23f7890: mydb/postgres@unix:6432 login attempt: db=mydb user=postgres
28864 LOG C-0x23f7890: mydb/postgres@unix:6432 closing because: client unexpected eof (age=0)
28864 LOG C-0x23f7890: mydb/postgres@unix:6432 login attempt: db=mydb user=postgres
28864 LOG S-0x2415240: mydb/postgres@127.0.0.1:5432 new connection to server
28864 LOG S-0x2415240: mydb/postgres@127.0.0.1:5432 closing because: connect failed (age=0)
28864 LOG S-0x2415240: mydb/postgres@127.0.0.1:5432 new connection to server
28864 LOG S-0x2415240: mydb/postgres@127.0.0.1:5432 closing because: connect failed (age=0)
28864 LOG S-0x2415240: mydb/postgres@127.0.0.1:5432 new connection to server
28864 LOG S-0x2415240: mydb/postgres@127.0.0.1:5432 closing because: connect failed (age=0)
28864 LOG S-0x2415240: mydb/postgres@127.0.0.1:5432 new connection to server
28864 LOG S-0x2415240: mydb/postgres@127.0.0.1:5432 closing because: connect failed (age=0)
28864 LOG Stats: 0 req/s, in 0 b/s, out 0 b/s,query 0 us
28864 LOG C-0x23f7890: mydb/postgres@unix:6432 closing because: client_login_timeout (server down) (age=60)
28864 WARNING C-0x23f7890: mydb/postgres@unix:6432 Pooler Error: client_login_timeout (server down)
28864 LOG Stats: 0 req/s, in 0 b/s, out 0 b/s,query 0 us
28864 LOG Stats: 0 req/s, in 0 b/s, out 0 b/s,query 0 us
```

Is there something else I need to change to make pgbouncer work?

Comment: Firewall blocking packets one-way?

Comment: Hmm, seems strange. Im testing the connection locally and externally:

tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6432    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27040/pgbouncer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
listen_addresses = 'private_ip'
```

to

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

In the `postgresql.conf` file.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to connect using a Unix socket. Depending on your Postgres installation, the socket may have been created in /tmp rather than /var/run/postgres. I've run into this same issue and it has been [discussed here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/21044.1326496507@sss.pgh.pa.us).

Try changing the pgbouncer.ini config to this:

```
unix_socket_dir = /tmp
```

You could also try just connecting to localhost by adding the -h as follows:

```
 psql -p 6432 -h localhost -U postgres mydb
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The error was in my postgresql.conf file. My listen_adresses was set to not accept local incoming. Changed it to listen_addresses = '*' and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue seemed to be when I defined the database in the `[databases]` section of the config file; I was not able to use `host=127.0.0.1` or `host=localhost`, but I had to use the actual IP, `host=192.168.0.1`. This could be due to a misconfigured postgresql `pg_hba.conf` file, but I couldn't find a way to make it work with local IPs.