# PgBouncer - Server DNS lookup failed

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer, postgresql-14, pgbench

I am trying to test PgBouncer connection with pgbench on a PostgreSQL server. But I'm getting error as `closing because: server DNS lookup failed` and at pgbench getting this message:

```
pgbench -c 10 -t 10 -C -f C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\query.sql -U postgres -p 6432 -n tags
Password:
pgbench: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 6432 failed: FATAL:  client_login_timeout (server down)
```

This is observed in PgBouncer log:

```
LOG C-01715ff0: tags/postgres@[::1]:52768 login attempt: db=tags user=postgres tls=no
WARNING DNS lookup failed: localhost: result=11001
LOG S-0174d218: tags/postgres@(bad-af):0 closing because: server DNS lookup failed (age=0s)
```

I'm running PostgreSQL-14.5 on Windows Server 2019

PgBouncer Config:

```
[databases]
postgres = host=localhost port=5435
tags = dbname=postgres host=localhost port=5435 user=postgres password=Admin@!23 auth_user=postgres

[pgbouncer]
logfile = C:\Program Files (x86)\PgBouncer\log\pgbouncer.log
pidfile = C:\Program Files (x86)\PgBouncer\log\pgbouncer.pid
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432
auth_type = md5
auth_file = C:\Program Files (x86)\PgBouncer\etc\userlist.txt
admin_users = postgres
stats_users = postgres
pool_mode = session
max_client_conn = 100
default_pool_size = 20
```

I tried solutions suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036019/pgbouncer-cant-connect-to-local-postgresql-database-timeout), like, setting
`listen_addresses = '*'` in `postgresql.conf`
but could not get the issue resolved. I also searched over the internet for the solution & did not find any.
Am I missing anything or please suggest a solution to this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like pgbouncer is unable to use DNS.  How did you install pgbouncer?  What if you change its config to specify the IP address rather than 'localhost'?

Comment: I installed pgbouncer with Stackbuilder. After changing my pgbouncer.ini configurations I'm able to connect to Postgres DB.
` [databases] `
`tags = host=127.0.0.1 port=5435 auth_user=postgres dbname=postgres `

Answer (score 0):

I can connect to Postgres DB after setting [databases] configuration in pgbouncer.ini like this :  `tags = host=127.0.0.1 port=5435 auth_user=postgres dbname=postgres`.

Turns out the issue was with `localhost` not added in `pg_hba.conf`.